# Example from Zorich's book on the boundary of open ball in $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $B(a;r)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^m: d(a,x)<r\}$ be an open ball centered at $a$ of radius $r>0$. Let $S(a;r)=\{x\in
>  \mathbb{R}^m: d(a,x)=r\}$ be a sphere centered at $a$ of radius $r>0$.

> **Definition 5.** In relation to a set $E\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ a point $x\in \mathbb{R}^m$ is
>
> *an interior point* if some neighborhood of it is contained in $E$;
>
> *an exterior point* if it is an interior point of the complement of $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$;
>
> *a boundary point* if it neither an interior point nor an exterior point.

> It follows from this definition that the characteristic property of a
> boundary point of a set is that every neighborhood of it contains both
> points of the set and points not in the set.
>
> **Example 7.** The sphere $S(a;r), r>0$ is the set of boundary points of boths the open ball $B(a;r)$ and the closed ball
> $\overline{B}(a;r)$

I have some issues with this example.

I am trying to show that $\partial B(a;r)=S(a;r)$.

Firstly let's prove that $\partial B(a;r)\subset S(a;r)$. Suppose this is not true, then $\exists x\in \partial B(A;r)$ such that $x\notin S(a;r)$. If $d(a,x)<r$, then $x$ is an interior point of $B(a,r)$ because $B(a,r)$ is an open set. Similarly, if $d(a,x)>r$, then we know that $G:=\{z\in \mathbb{R}^m: d(a,z)>r\}$ is an open set. Hence for some $\delta>0$ we have $B(x,\delta)\subset G \subset \{z\in \mathbb{R}^m: d(a,z)\geq r\}=\mathbb{R}^m\setminus B(a;r)$ which means that $x$ is an exterior point of $B(a;r)$. So in both cases we have contradiction which proves the desired containment.

Now. I am gonna prove that $S(a;r)\subset \partial B(a;r)$. If this is not true then there is an $x\in S(a;r)$ so that $x\notin \partial B(a;r)$. Since $x$ is not a boundary point, then $x$ is an interior point or exterior point of $B(a;r)$.

If $x$ is an interior point of $B(a;r)$, then there exists a neighborhood of $x$, say $U$ such that $x\in U\subset B(a;r)$. Hence $d(a;x)<r$ which is a contradiction since $x\in S(a;r)$.

What if $x$ is an exterior point of $B(a;r)$? I am trying to do the same reasoning but it fails. Intuitively is clear that $d(x,a)>r$ but cannot prove it rigorously.

Can enyone help me to finish it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d$ is the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^m$.

If $x$ is an exterior point of $B(a;r)$, then there exists an open $U$ such that $x \in U \subset \mathbb R^m \setminus B(a;r)$. Since $U$ is open, there exists $s > 0$ such that $B(x;s) \subset U$. Hence $B(x;s) \cap B(a;r) = \emptyset$.

Since $x \in S(a;r)$, we have $d(a,x) = r$. Choose $t > 0$ such that $1-s/r < t < 1$ and define $y = tx + (1-t)a$. Then $$d(x,y) = \lVert x -y \rVert = \lVert (1-t)(x-a) \rVert = (1-t)\lVert (x-a) \rVert =(1-t)d(x,a) = (1-t)r < (s/r) r = s .$$ Thus $y \in B(x;s)$. On the other hand
$$d(a,y) = \lVert a -y \rVert = \lVert t(a-x) \rVert = t \lVert a-x \rVert <\lVert a-x \rVert =d(a,x) = r .$$
Thus $y \in B(a;r)$. We conclude that $y \in  B(x;s) \cap B(a;r)$, a contradiction.

Comment: I see it now! Very nice! Can you explain what was the idea behind the proof? I see that you are considering the line from $a$ to $x$. But what is the point of taking $t$ in such a smart way?

Comment: @RFZ The idea is indeed to take a point $y = tx +(1-t)a = a +t(x-a)$ on the line from $a$ to $x$ which lies strictly between $a$ and $x$ (which means taking $0 < t < 1$) and is suffiently close to $x$. The latter means $d(x,y) < s$ and you can easily insert $y$ to determine $t$.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot for such a nice answer! +1

Comment: @RFZ Also note that the proof only works with a metric induced by some norm on a vector space. The theorem is wrong in general metric spaces. Look at the discrete metric on a set $X$.

Comment: Hmm! I did not know this. Thanks for this. Just to clarify your example: Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space with discrete metric $d$. Here the equality $\partial B(a;1)=S(a;1)$ fails because $B(a;1)=\{a\}$ and $S(a;1)=X\setminus\{a\}$. But in this setting $\partial B(a;r)=\partial a=\varnothing$. Right?

Comment: @RFZ This is correct.